# Is a domain joined windows machine's objectGUID or ObjectSID as stored by Active Directory also stored locally?

Tags: windows, active-directory

Working on an inventory project where I need to link a computer to an object in Active Directory.

I have an export of all computer objects from Active Directory including some unique identifiers such as objectGUID and objectSID.

I now need to query the local device (ideally via powershell) for one of those unique identifiers so I can positively link the device to the computer object in Active Directory. The device may be off network, and not able to access a domain controller when it is queried.

Is the Active Directory computer object's objectGUID or objectSID attribute stored locally on a domain joined computer?

Comment: NO, in my experience! You have AD level GUID stored on DC, different UUID of local system, and additional MachineGUID in registry (HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid).

Comment: You may also like to refer: [Looking for a unique GUID to identify a Windows installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/93785/looking-for-a-unique-guid-to-identify-a-windows-installation)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I am seeing as well. I cannot seem to find an identifier that can be used to link a machine back to a computer object in AD.

Comment: Stephen F, were you able to devise a solution or workaround?